# Launch a Python Job using "SCHEDULE" for Beginners

Tags: python, cron, schedule

I have never written a cron job or used the 'SCHEDULE' function in python to automatically run a program. So, i need some guidance please. My program runs fine and I need it to run on the 15th day of every month - so 12 times per year. I tried to run this as a test by setting  schedule.every().day.at("7:30").do(job) and nothing happened. In other words, the code did not run as I have it configured below at 7:30. Again, i need this to run on the 15th day of each month. Do i need to *rearrange* the parts of my code(rows) to make this script run automatically as expected? Thank you,

My code looks like this:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from sys import exit
from tabulate import tabulate
import schedule
import time

#schedule 
def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every().month.at("15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

from datetime import datetime
start_time = datetime.now()
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
#My code runs below from here....
```

CODE NOT SHOWN

```
end_time = datetime.now()
print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))

exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The scheduled part of your code is in the job function. So don't put actions that can be executed only once in it (like `pd.set_option` or `import`)

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from sys import exit
from tabulate import tabulate
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

#schedule 
def job():
    print("I'm working...")
    #Put your code here
    start_time = datetime.now()
    # Some more code
    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))


schedule.every().month.at("15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

You should remove the  `exit()` as it will kill your process after one execution.

But in your case I doubt that you want to have a python process up all year long to trigger an action every month. Using the unix crontab to execute your python script seems a lot more appropriate, and you can remove all the scheduling logic from your code.

Comment: thanks - let's say i could have a python process up and running so the program will launch automatically. What would that look like - or how would i modify my code above? that is the part that i'm not understanding - launching the program and how to do it..

Comment: Sorry I misread your code, you have the `while True` that will keep your job running so this part is ok. To run it, open a terminal and execute `python script.py` (or whatever your script name is)

Comment: OK! so, i can leave my code as is above and call the script as you suggest from the terminal?

Comment: Your script will only print "I'm working..." as only the job function will be executed by the scheduler. So put your code there and you can launch it in the terminal. I edit my answer as it is not correct